# Plot Using User-defined Coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, coordinate-transformation, coordinate

Suppose instead of using Cartesian coordinate $\vec{x}=(1, 0)$ and $\vec{y}=(0, 1)$, I want to define new coordiates $\vec{a} = (1,0)$ and $\vec{b} = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} )$. And when I plot a function for example $f(\vec{r}) = f(c, d)$

> f[c_, d_] := d
>
> Plot3D[f[c, d], {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}]

Is there a way it will interpret the plotting region and function as $d*\vec{b}$ instead of $d*\vec{y}$?

I know I can probably redefine the new unit vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as Cartesian coordinate but it would be convenient if I can redefine the coordinate system.

I hope I'm clear enough what I'm trying to do and thanks in advnace!

Comment: maybe `f2 = Rescale[f[##], {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}/2] &;Plot3D[f2[c, d], {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[c_, d_] := d

p1 = Plot3D[f[c, d], {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 300];

f2 = Rescale[f[##], {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}/2] &;

p2 = Plot3D[ f2[c, d], {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{p1, p2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]